# TreeSet.map results in unsorted outcome in Scala

Tags: scala

I am using a TreeSet to keep a set in memory while sorted according to a special ordering. This works fine. When I map it, though, it loses its order.

I've used a debugger to look at it and I see that the TreeSet is indeed sorted correctly (I have created a special Ordering implementation, the objects sorted are not simple). However, I also used a debugger to look at what happens post the call to "map" and it's a mess.

This is the code, and I've attached screenshots from the debugger:

```
cmd._2.asInstanceOf[MonitoringCommandExecutionResult].metrics.map(metric => {
      metric match {
      case ComplexMetric(tags, value, timeStamp) =>
      s"""{
       |"tags": [ ${printTags(tags)} ],
       |"value": ${value.compactPrint}
            }                          """.stripMargin
      case DoubleMetric(tags, value, timeStamp) =>
      s"""{
       |"tags": [ ${printTags(tags)} ],
       |"value": "${value}"
       }""".stripMargin
    }
  })
```

[image: Sorted TreeSet]
[image: Messy HashSet, resulting from map]

Comment: What order did you expect the result to have? Logically, mapping over a `TreeSet` should result in a `TreeSet` as well, and since it would be a `TreeSet[String]` it would order the string representations alphabetically, which is probably not what you want. Also, it's a `Set`, so if 2 or more metrics have the same string representation, all except one would be deleted. If you want to have the original order preserved, convert the `Set` to a `Seq` before mapping.

Comment: I expected it to be the same order as the original TreeSet had. Your comment regarding converting to Set prior to mapping hit the nail on the head. Thank you!